# Are these sunchoke insects friend or foe?

Tags: identification, insects

I've never seen many insects on my Jerusalem artichokes before but this year they seem to be plentiful. Are they pests? They do seem to be having a good time and there doesn't seem to be any leaf damage though those black spots look like insect feces.

[image: enter link description here]
[image: enter link description here]

My guess is that they're probably some type of leafhopper.

Comment: This second picture is XXX.  I am in a huge snit.  "They seem to be having a good time"...they certainly do not look like they are harming your plants at all at the moment...I gotta pull it together.  Graham...major grins!

Comment: The first picture is definitely a leaf hopper.  Which one exactly is beyond me at the moment.